# MySQL dump file and commented out lines

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql

I have these lines at the top of a MySQL .sql file (dumped with phpMyAdmin):

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
```

But they all seem to be commented out. So will MySQL ignore them when the file is loaded back into a database? If so, why generate these lines at all?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

These are conditional comments aimed at certain versions of mySQL.

From [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20110307151447/http://www.poundbangwhack.com/2010/07/14/mysql-quick-tip-target-specific-versions-of-mysql-with-conditional-comments/) and [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comments.html):

- MySQL version specific comments start with `/*!`
- And end with `*/`
- Version numbers are always 5 digits
- Version numbers are in the format major release number, 
  minor release number, revision number with the major being 1 digit 
  and the minor and revision being 2 digits left-padded with 0’s
- Version specific comments will target any version equal to or higher than
   the version number listed

Comment: @Unicron It might not always be for specific version, because I tried dumping a file with mysql view, this view is defined commented out, it has nothing to do with mysql version.

Answer (score 8):

MySQL *will* parse and execute these lines of code, I believe for localization and character-encoding stuff, because the comments start with `/*!` (with the exclamation mark) instead of just the C-style `/*`.

Think of it the same way you do conditional comments and Internet Explorer. `<!--[if IE]><![endif]-->` looks like any plain old HTML comment to other browsers, but IE recognizes this special comment and parses it as needed. Likewise, `/*! */` looks like any other comment to other SQL DBMSes but is special to MySQL.