# Unclear result of mysqldump

Tags: sql, mysql

Why are these lines present in output of mysqldump?

```
  /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
  /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
  /*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
  /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
  /*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
  /*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
  /*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
  /*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
```

They have been commented and start with `![some number]`. What does it mean?

Comment: Just some variable options from mysql,nothing to worry about.

Comment: It's setting some variables, but why are they commented and what are these numbers for?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL dump file and commented out lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257115/mysql-dump-file-and-commented-out-lines)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This

```
/*!40014
```

just makes sure, that the following command is executed only, if the MySQL version is at least `4.00.14`.

This

```
SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT
```

stores the current settings of MySQL. Variables starting with `@@` are system variables, variables starting with `@` are user defined variables.

After the import of data is finished, MySQL will restore the original state with statements the other way round, such as

```
/*!40101 SET @@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
```

Comment: Worth noting that /*! is a special comment in mysql where it knows to actually execute part of it given some conditions pass. Same as with javadocs in Java /** is parsed and executed to display javadocs where // comments are not parsed.